# how to iterate through each columns and each cells in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, classification, data-mining

I have a dataframe (`training_df`) with 4 columns each containing about 150 rows. I also have function as follows:

```
def normalise(theMin, theMax, theVal):
    if(theMin == theVal):
        return 0
    else if(theMax == theVal):
        return 1
    return (theVal - theMin) / (theMax - theMin)
```

Now, what I want to do is to iterate through all four columns of my dataframe in turn and iterate through all the rows in each column and for each value in the rows (there will of course be only one cell in each row) I want to replace them with whatever value is returned from the `normalise` function. So I tried something like this by looking at the already asked questions in this forum:

```
for column in training_df:
    theMin = training_df[column].min()
    theMax = training_df[column].max()    
    for i in training_df[[column]].iterrows():
        training_df[[column[i]]] = normalise(theMin, theMax, i)
```

But I get a `TypeError: string indices must be integers` I am quite new to Python and pandas and to data mining, so if somebody could clarify this a bit would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I will do ..

```
df.apply(lambda x : (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min()))
```

Comment: `df = df - df.min() / (df.max() - df.min())` also works

Comment: Thank you for your response @Wen. The problem is not the function, it is returning the value I need every time when I test it. The problem occurs when I try to replace the values in the dataframe. The following part is working fine: for column in training_df:
    theMin = training_df[column].min()
    theMax = training_df[column].max() But when I try to replace the values in each cell by the returned value, it gives me an error

Comment: @SedatTurkoglu change to `for x,i in training_df[[column]].iterrows():
        training_df.loc[x,column]= normalise(theMin, theMax, i[0])
`

Comment: Awesome @Wen, thats excatly what I needed Thanks a lot :)